# Correct way to define macros \etc \ie in latex

Tags: latex

In 
[this article](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/827168808/correct-punctuation-spaces) the author discusses the use of \@ to put correct spacings after full stops that are not at the end of a sentence e.g. Mr. i.e. etc.

The macro suggested

```
\newcommand\etc{etc\@ifnextchar.{}{.\@}}
```

is not quite perfect since in the case `(\etc more text)` it produces `(etc.more text)`.

I have seen a lot of authors who have made their own versions of the `\etc` macro, mostly variations on `etc.\`.

What macros for `\etc`, `\ie`, `\etal`, `\eg` produce the nicest results in the most situations?

Is this something too personal in taste to be solved in general?

Comment: This has been my favourite SO [latex] qn in a long time.

Comment: I have used \xspace for my \etc-like macros, and looking at it, it gives me the wrong spacing and I never noticed.  I'm glad I read this question.

Comment: @Ivan - What are the counter examples? I posted an answer a few days ago and just saw this comment.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  I was using etc.\xspace rather than etc.\@\xspace and that naturally caused problems.

Comment: Related question on tex.stackexchange: [Good practice on spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5511/175).

Comment: @CharlesStewart Should this be migrated to tex.SE altogether?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Earlier I used macros for "et al.", etc., but nowadays I would discourage people from defining that kind of macros.

One problem is what you already observed: it's surprisingly tricky to get the definitions right so that they handle all special cases correctly (including the interactions with other packages – e.g., those that re-define the "\cite" command and tweak spacing before references).

But more importantly, even if *you* have a bunch of macros that suit your needs and you know how to use them, your *co-authors* are likely to be confused with exactly how to use your macros correctly in various special cases.

Hence I'd recommend that you avoid macros for trivial things such as "et al." and simply spell out everything by using standard Latex markup. After all, most cases don't need any special handling ("e.g." is often followed by a comma; "et al." is often followed by "~\cite", etc.), and whenever special handling is needed, all Latex users should know how to use commands such as "\ " and "\@".

Comment: I agree with the "cure is worse than the disease" sentiment of your answer, but *all Latex users should know how to use commands such as "\ " and "\@"* lost me: did you know that Tex puts extra space after the period in ".)"?  If you did, congratulations, you are an elite TeXnician. If not, then you didn't know the proper usage of \@, which is what led to the question.  The way Tex digests your text is very tricky, tricky enough that someone like Will Robertson can get caught out.

Comment: Charles: Oh, sorry, I was referring to simpler (and much more common) cases that are covered in virtually any Latex tutorial. Sure, I agree that the case of ".)" is indeed surprising, and it was nice to learn something new from the original question. :) However, I think that intricacies like this are a good reason not to try to fix it by using macros...

Comment: Seems this is the best way to go (at least until LaTeX3 becomes standard).

Comment: +1. Charles just pointed out a really important case that makes me think this answer is correct -- when an abbreviation ends a sentence. How can you deal with this? Is there any way a single macro of any wisdom could ever tell if the period ends a sentence?

Comment: @Geoff: [This web site](http://john.regehr.org/latex/) contains some LaTeX tips, and briefly comments about the macro and spaces issue. The author mentions the package `xspace`, which according to him is a `heuristic for defeating LaTeX behavior of chomping a space following a macro in the case where the space was supposed to be preserved in the output`. I didn't really read too much because I got to that site briefly and for other reasons, but it may help you, or at least I hope so. Regards.

Answer (score 17):

In CVPR's style package, it is defined as:

```latex
\usepackage{xspace}

% Add a period to the end of an abbreviation unless there's one
% already, then \xspace.
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}

\def\eg{\emph{e.g}\onedot} \def\Eg{\emph{E.g}\onedot}
\def\ie{\emph{i.e}\onedot} \def\Ie{\emph{I.e}\onedot}
\def\cf{\emph{c.f}\onedot} \def\Cf{\emph{C.f}\onedot}
\def\etc{\emph{etc}\onedot} \def\vs{\emph{vs}\onedot}
\def\wrt{w.r.t\onedot} \def\dof{d.o.f\onedot}
\def\etal{\emph{et al}\onedot}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using the `xspace` package?

**Example macro:**

```
\def\etc{etc.\@\xspace}
```

**Some tests:**

> ```
> Cat, dog, \etc. And so on.   \\
> Cat, dog, \etc! And so on.   \\
> Cat, dog, \etc, and so on.   \\
> Cat (dog, \etc). And so on.  \\
> ```

**Produces:**

[image]

---

From [the documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/xspace.html):

> The xspace package provides a single
>   command that looks at what comes after
>   it in the command stream, and decides
>   whether to insert a space to replace
>   one "eaten" by the TeX command
>   decoder.

Comment: You need to gobble the abbreviation's period in your first test (i.e., not "etc.."), so you need to test the next character as well.  But you are quite right, the xspace package can be used instead of explicitly testing ahead for catcode 10.

Comment: Oh. Wow, good point. So the first example is wrong. I wasn't aware of this grammar rule somehow.

Comment: So, in your example `Maybe a list, \eg,` a list should be `Maybe a list, \eg.,` since your macro does not have the ending period in it. I see now why you don't include the ending period in your macro. Thanks.

Comment: The first is explicitly forbidden in all the guides I've looked that talk about abbreviations at the end of sentences, e.g., Butcher (2009) Copy-editing lists it among *Common faults of punctuation*.  The second is problematic: I'd contract the ".!" to "!", but I don't know of any guide that says you must.  My code doesn't treat this case.

Answer (score 5):

A technical challenge!  We can avoid the problem of letters after spaces by looking at the catcode of the next character and seeing whether or not it is a letter; this can be done with the Latex3's expl3 macro `\peek_charcode:NTF` (my first expl3 code!):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\latinabbrev[1]{
  \peek_meaning:NTF . {% Same as \@ifnextchar
    #1\@}%
  { \peek_catcode:NTF a {% Check whether next char has same catcode as \'a, i.e., is a letter
      #1.\@ }%
    {#1.\@}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%Omit final dot from each def.
\def\eg{\latinabbrev{e.g}}
\def\etal{\latinabbrev{et al}}
\def\etc{\latinabbrev{etc}}
\def\ie{\latinabbrev{i.e}}

\begin{document}

Maybe a list, \eg, a, b, c, and d.  Which is to say (\ie) a, b, \etc.  Consider Knuth, \cf The TeXbook.

\end{document}
```

Jukka's advice I think is sound, though: I'd say the problem Will works around with his \etc macro we should see as a bug in Tex's implementation of double spacing (Will Robertson should ask for his cheque): if you know the bug is there, you can workaround it directly by putting in \@ in cases such as ".)", or you can have tricky code that means you don't have to think in this case, but you have added complexity to the way you typeset which is not going to work for you with the next unexpected glitch, one you probably have introduced yourself.

**Postscript** Previous version fixed, thanks to [Joseph Wright noticing a stupid error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438/how-to-test-whether-next-token-on-input-stream-is-catcode-10/442#442) at tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It is "et al.", short for "et alii".

Comment: Also, I believe there should be a little, unbreakable space in "i.e." and "e.g.".

Comment: @Svante: *et al.* - indeed, fixed;  *Little, unbreakable space* - I've never heard of that, and I can't see it in any book I've looked at: are you sure?

Comment: @Charles Stewart: I am not entirely sure, but I think that actually, it should be "i. e.".  One would not like to have this broken at a linebreak, so it has become customary to type it "i.e." in "computer texts", but in TeX, it would better be "i.~e.".  It might be a good idea to make this space a little smaller, but eliminating it entirely does not look right.

Comment: I don't think that the way Tex handles ".)" is (strictly speaking) a bug. (Consider a parenthetical remark – like this – that consists of several sentences and ends with a full stop. I think Tex does the right thing if it adds extra space after the closing parenthesis.) That said, I guess I would be happier if Tex didn't try to guess anything and there was simply a special markup that denotes end of sentence, but it's a bit too late to change that...

Comment: @Svante: I'm looking at the Chicago MoS, 5.202, "i.e.; e.g." and it looks to me that there's quite a bit less horizontal space in "i.e." (in bold) between the dot and the "e" than between the "i" and the dot. It appears that they're using microtypography to reduce the space.

Comment: @Jukka: Look at this fragment of your answer, where I use underscore to inicate space: "closing_parenthesis.__)_That_said".  Do you really want more space before the parenthesis than after?  So that the closing parenthesis is grouped with the following sentence?

Comment: @Charles: Tex typesets it like "closing_parenthesis.)__That_said", not "closing_parenthesis.__)_That_said".

Comment: @Charles Nice, though the whole academic publishing paradigm will probably be overturned before LaTeX3 becomes common enough with publishers. I havnt yet found how to trigger the "Check if next char is a letter" clause. For example `\eg an example`.

Comment: @Jukka: Sorry, yes, you are quite right and I had confused myself.  In fact, the point Will made in his weblog post is precisely that ".) " is spaced as if it is the end of the sentence (i.e., ".)__"), even though the dot doesn't end the sentence.  I wasn't confused in my answer, though, and I still say it is in bug territory, but I'll leave it at that for now.

Comment: @Niall: Err, yes, my code doesn't work in this crucial case.  I'll look at it when I have a bit more time.

Comment: I just found a package called `xspace` that seems to give the functionality you implemented (without needing `expl3`). Would you please check the examples in my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All LaTeX commands eliminate space after them.  If you want a space, you need to escape it:

```
\etc\ and more
```

This is necessary, because you need to be clear where the command name ends.  `\etcno space` cannot be correctly interpreted.

Comment: But you can lookahead to see if the next character is catcode 10, to see if there should have been a space: see my answer.

Comment: Sorry to keep nitpicking: it's actually not true that all commands eliminate space: only those composed of letters (i.e., catcode 10 characters do).  Other commands defined in the normal way (i.e., not using `\csname`) are one character long control sequences and don't gobble space.  This is exactly why it's a good idea to look at the next character's catcode.

Comment: I found a package `xspace` that can check to see if you need the space. Will you take a look at my answer, and see if there are any counter examples? Thanks.